# Putting today's date in excel header formatting as "March 3, 2016"

Tags: vba, excel

Some googling lead me to [this article](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010678_Putting_a_Different_Date_in_a_Header.html) which says that it's not possible without a macro but it's published for 2013 excel and maybe they're wrong.   Anyone know how I can do this without a macro?  Or if I have to do it with a macro, is there a way to do it like in header have a custom variable like &[todays_date_formatted] or something that I can define with VBA?

Comment: did you at least try to go to "More Number Formatting" and check the formatting options on "Date"? There is one exactly like this...

Comment: I have not found that the list of custom header options, and the applicable codes, are part of a property accessible to VBA. You could use a Workbook_BeforePrint event triggered macro and, depending on how flexible you needed this to be, have it present a form where you could enter your custom header with formatting.  Although if you only wanted to have Today's date with your desired formatting, it'd probably be easiest to hardcode that.

Comment: @juanora, either I've missed the obvious or you missed the part where I said 'in header'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without VBA*
Using *only* formulas
Put this in a cell:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"mmmm d, yyyy")
```

And it resolves to:

```
March 4, 2016
```

If you want to do it in VBA:

```
'Place this function in a Standard Module
Public Function todays_date_formatted() as String
  todays_date_formatted = Format(Now(), "mmmm d, yyyy")
End Function
```

And then call it from other VBA, or from your worksheet, using the formula:

```
=todays_date_formatted()
```

But in all of the above, the date is converted to a string, so you lose the ability to directly use the value in date arithmetic, *and* the results *may* vary across language and region.

As others have suggested, I'd recommend using the built-in number-format on a cell with `=Now()` in it. If you don't have a built-in number format that works, just create a custom format, and use this format string:

```
mmmm d, yyyy
```

**Edit - Make it work with Page Header**

This will update the header for a sheet called Sheet1, but you can change it to the codename of any specific sheet.

You'll probably need to keep a cell (or a defined name) with a formula that includes this function, so the sheet header will get updated whenever you calculate.

```
Public Function todays_date_formatted() As String
  Dim sFormattedDate As String
  sFormattedDate = Format(Now(), "mmmm d, yyyy")

  'Change 'Sheet1' to the codename of the sheet header you want to update
  Sheet1.PageSetup.CenterHeader = sFormattedDate
  todays_date_formatted = sFormattedDate
End Function
```

Comment: Same question -- how do you use that to alter the Page `Header`?

Comment: Sorry - missed the bit about the header - have updated my answer.

Comment: This would be great if I only needed the date in the right side of the header.  But I need other information in the header on the right side. So this script would over write all of that.

Comment: @clickhere Just add the other information to the script.

Comment: Definitely wanted to only use VBA as a last resort so I wanted to consider all other possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

One image worth more than thousand words:
[image]

Comment: How does formatting a cell change the format in a page Header in Excel?